# How can custom properties be added to a column in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

With doctrine if you execute this code

```
$columns = $accountTable->getColumns();
foreach ($columns as $column)
{
    print_r($column);
}
```

you could get for example this as result:

```
Array
(
    [type] => integer
    [length] => 20
    [autoincrement] => 1
    [primary] => 1
)
Array
(
    [type] => string
    [length] => 255
)
```

Is there a way to add custom properties to a column, so that the result would be:

```
Array
(
    [type] => integer
    [length] => 20
    [autoincrement] => 1
    [primary] => 1
    [customproperty] => customvalue
)
Array
(
    [type] => string
    [length] => 255
)
```

Comment: I'd like to use customproperties for determining a rendertype (textbox, textarea, checkbox, ...) in a custom formgenerator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$accountTable->setColumnOption('column', 'option', 'value');
```

If you want this to persist, you're probably best off setting this in the AccountTable class itself.

Comment: Sweet! I can see this method in the sourcecode, but it is not documented in the Doctrine 1.2 documentation

Comment: Is there a way to specify this in a yaml-file?

Comment: Don't think so, but you can add custom properties in the generated models/tables.